# UICollectionView header doesn't appear?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I've put UICollectionView inside UICollectionView header the images inside the the header doesn't appear till I wrote:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let index = NSIndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
  self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [index as IndexPath])
 }
```

but the simulator sometimes crashes is this line !

So any suggestions, ideas ?

Comment: Have you added Headerview height for the collectionview? @Mohammad

Comment: Absolutely, ya. the size of header is visible but doesn't have any images !

Comment: How you add Header view in your project ? If you adding through storyboard, then try add in code.

Comment: I have added header in code not from IB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve it by checking the index of the visible cell:

```
let Visibleindex = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
    for index in 0..<Visibleindex.count {
        if index == 0 {
            let index = NSIndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
            self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [index as IndexPath])
        }
    }
```